# Swift IndexPath counting continuous over multiple sections?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, prototype

I have multiple sections in a UITableView. I am using the IndexPath of the cells to set some values. What I am asking is if at the start of a new section, the counting of the IndexPaths restarts to zero. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `IndexPath` has `section` and `row` properties. Within each sections, the row numbers start at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does. If you implement the basic example below, you'll see how the row index restarts from 0 in each section

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    let myDataSource = ["Andrew", "Anthony", "Bill", "Brad", "Charlie", "Craig"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.myCellLabel.text = myDataSource[indexPath.row + indexPath.section*2] + "  [Row = \(indexPath.row), Section = \(indexPath.section)]"
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        var title = ""
        switch section {
        case 0:
            title = "A"
        case 1:
            title = "B"
        case 2:
            title = "C"
        default:
            break
        }

        return title
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!